# can't restart etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, apache2

I'm getting this error "AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.166.136. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message".
As a solution on the internet, they told me to add "ServerName mydomain.com" to the apache2.conf file with the echo command, but after adding it, I cannot restart this file.

I cannot change this file with nano vim. This apache2.conf file is located under the etc/apache2/ path in the wordpress container on a kubernetes.

When I restart my apache2.conf file with commands like these: "kubectl exec -it your-pod-name -- service apache2 restart". The file terminates itself and reloads from the image.
"Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2command terminated with exit code 143"

"/etc/apache2/apache2.conf Reload"
"bash: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Permission denied"

Comment: The linked question describes some things you can change in your application's Dockerfile, generally using a Dockerfile `RUN` directive to add the `ServerName` directive at image build time.  You shouldn't try to use `kubectl exec` in the way you describe: you can't change config files in multiple replicas, your changes will be lost if the Pod is ever recreated (possibly outside your control), and you can't usually restart the main container process without terminating the container.